# Extract last ","

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code

```
function convertToCurr(value) {
    var x = value.toString().length;
    var z = x % 3;
    var a = 0;
        if (z == 0) {
            a = (x / 3) - 1;
        }
        else {
            a = (x / 3);
        }
    var last = 0;
    var vals = [];
    var i;
        for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
            steps = 3;
            start = x - steps * i;
            end = start + steps;
            last = end - steps;
            vals.unshift(value.toString().slice(start, end));
        }
    vals.unshift("R " + value.toString().slice(0, last));
   
     return vals.join();
}
basicIO.write(convertToCurr(input));
context.log.INFO("log data");
```

}
These are my outputs
{"output":"R 1,000,000,.00","log":["log data"]}
{"output":"R 1,000,.00","log":["log data"]}

I need to exctract the last "," so that the amounts make sense

Comment: `'R 1,000,000,.00'.replace(',.', '.')`

Comment: You mean get rid of the last comma in your output number? eg. `"R 1,000.00"`

Comment: Yes Sir that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is to perform a [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on the final `join()`.

```js
function convertToCurr(value) {
    var x = value.toString().length;
    var z = x % 3;
    var a = 0;
        if (z == 0) {
            a = (x / 3) - 1;
        }
        else {
            a = (x / 3);
        }
    var last = 0;
    var vals = [];
    var i;
        for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
            steps = 3;
            start = x - steps * i;
            end = start + steps;
            last = end - steps;
            vals.unshift(value.toString().slice(start, end));
        }
    vals.unshift("R " + value.toString().slice(0, last));
   
     return vals.join().replace(',.', '.');
}

console.log(convertToCurr(10000.75));
console.log(convertToCurr(10.01));
console.log(convertToCurr(1000));
console.log(convertToCurr(7002344));
```

It should be noted that `replace()` only replaces a *single instance* of the substring you provide it in the input string, but this doesn't matter here since `,.` only appears in your output string one time.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertToCurr(value) {
    var x = value.toString().length;
    var z = x % 3;
    var a = 0;
    var combinedString; // holds string value after join
    if (z == 0) {
        a = x / 3 - 1;
    } else {
        a = x / 3;
    }
    var last = 0;
    var vals = [];
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
        steps = 3;
        start = x - steps * i;
        end = start + steps;
        last = end - steps;
        vals.unshift(value.toString().slice(start, end));
    }
    vals.unshift("R " + value.toString().slice(0, last));
    combinedString = vals.join(); // join array into string
    return combinedString.replace(",.", "."); // replace ,. with .
}

console.log(convertToCurr(50000000.15));
```